# Single Django Application, Multiple Instances

Tags: django, web-applications, django-models

I'm new to Django and have a question about Django application design.

I want to write one application and have multiple instances of it running, each under a different URL. Each instance would store its data in its own tables and each instance would have a different set of users. The different instances would be accessed from different URLs, but from the same domain and run the same application code behind the scenes.

For example if I had two instances, they would be accessed from the following URLs:

- http://www.domain.com/instance1
- http://www.domain.com/instance2

I've got my models defined, and I can run a single application, single instance, with multiple users just fine. However it's not clear to me how to support multiple instances.

I've taken a look at the sites framework, which is almost what I want, but I need everything to be hosted under the same domain.

Any tips on how I can run multiple instances of a single application with Django?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to have different subdomains instead of folders? This makes the Sites framework much easier to use.

Comment: Subdomains should be fine, does the sites framework support subdomains?

Comment: I've never tried it personally, but from Django's perspective, subdomains should be equivalent to separate domains. I believe sites framework relies on the `Host` header, which will be different for each subdomain.

Answer (score -2):

You could simply copy the django project to another place and create a new apache site.

For example:

Create a virtual host in /etc/apache2/sites-available/domain.eu_first

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain.eu
WSGIScriptAlias /first /var/www/first/wsgi

<Directory /var/www/first>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and

a virtual host in /etc/apache2/sites-available/domain.eu_second

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain.eu
WSGIScriptAlias /second /var/www/second/wsgi

<Directory /var/www/second>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now copy your project to first and second. And activate your apache sites by `a2ensite domain.eu_first` and `a2ensite domain.eu_second`

You have to proof that you have used only relativ links in your project.

Answer is unverified so just check it out.

Comment: Wouldn't this lead to lots of code duplications? Anytime I wanted to make a change I would have to make it in _n_ places where _n_ is the number of instances I am running.

Comment: Yes. Was just a workaround idea (for e.g. only 2 instances). I don't know, but it seams to be impossible to have two databases in one project (defined in settings).

Comment: I don't necessarily need two databases, I would like to separate my instances into their own tables, but if that's not possible, that's not an huge issue. If I drop that requirement is their a way to do this?